# Will you migrate your UI to using ribbons for Windows 7?

Tags: wpf, winforms, windows-client

Soon Windows 7 will use ribbon as default interface in any Windows programs, like Paint or WordPad, leaving to back default toolbars and menus.

Will you migrate your UI to using ribbons for Windows 7?

Comment: @zacherates you forgot to edit the "Do you will migrate your UI using ribbons for Windows 7?" inside the post, too ;)

Comment: Yes, I really need improve my english grammar... :-)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The main thing with the new ribbon in Office is NOT the different look and feel.  It's the effort and research that went into determining what elements needed to be placed where, how big, and understanding why.

If you're not prepared to duplicate that effort for your own app, it will probably be a bust.

Answer (score 7):

Did it last year. It was probably a mistake. The ribbon only works with applications that are definitely document-centric.

Trying to ram it into an application that doesn't want a ribbon because it looks good is not a good idea if it sacrifices usability.

I would say designing an application for use with a ribbon is a lot harder than a traditional menu/toolbar ui. You have to consider hard which commands belong together. The user is going to be annoyed if they have to flip tabs all the time to get to the commands they want.

Also, Microsoft impose many restrictions/limitations on how a ribbon can work. These are difficult to comply to, and could result in them legally forcing you to correct your application (if you can). Saying that, I think I've seen Microsoft's own use of the ribbon breaking their own guidelines. Maybe they've updated the guidelines since I last saw them!

Comment: I think the ribbons aren't very pretty imo.

Comment: The MS restrictions only apply if you use _their_ ribbon control.  Ribbon-like interfaces have been around longer than Office 2007.

Comment: Joel - I agree, I think Microsoft would have a job winning a case. Still, I'd hate to have to stand up to their legal team. I'm pretty sure though they aim to patent the concept, not just _their_ ribbon. See: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ribbon_(computing)

Comment: If you read Microsoft's licensing, they cover the style and use of their ribbon as a concept, not an actual control. So if you implement something that looks like their ribbon, but is all your own work, it's still covered under their license terms.

Answer (score 5):

If your software has clear, separate parts which all require their own set of controls the Ribbon could be very useful. In essence you could just use it as a tabbed toolbar and only let it switch when the user switches between the software parts.

In case of a software I'm currently working on there is a separate measuring, analyzing and reporting part in the software. Since I don't need measuring buttons while analyzing, it makes perfect sense to change the entire toolbar. The Ribbon is just an easy way to accomplish this.

*Note: we make the user switch between measuring and analyzing by changing the tab of the Ribbon, so it shouldn't happen that they "accidentally" get to see the measuring toolbar while being in analyzing.

If your software doesn't have a stockpile of functions like Word or has a clear distinction between software parts it would be better just to use a normal toolbar.

Answer (score 4):

In the interest of cross-platform consistency, no.

Comment: Consistency is the last bastion of the unimaginative. Most users only ever use one system so they won't have a clue that you steadfastly stuck to one look-and-feel.

Comment: On the other hand, users of the system you don't support thanks to implementing platform specific features might not be so inclined to use your software. It's not about reaching one user on multiple systems, but multiple users on multiple systems.

Answer (score 3):

I typed "no" so hard in this answer I bruised my wrist

Answer (score 2):

After awhile, yes. I think users are more accepting of new UI features from MS than from the rest of us developers. I'd rather wait for them to get used to this before they see it in our software.

Answer (score 2):

The bottom-line is you use the user interface concepts that make sense for your application, whether they be text boxes, labels, combos, menus, toolbars, images, buttons, lists, trees, ribbons, or some other concept. It's all about using the right tool for the job - just using a ribbon because it is there is as useful as converting all your combos to menus, or your toolbars to listboxes.

Only make the change if your application is improved by doing so.

Answer (score 0):

Unless I see an absolute need for it, then absolutely not. In my experience, most users I have come across dislike the Ribbon control because they find it hard to navigate, and they wish they had the old menu/toolbar style back.

Sure it looks nice, and can be organized nicely, but in the long run I don't think its a necessity for a lot of applications.

Visual navigation isn't always better.

Answer (score 0):

I usually don't use new features on the last versions of products: they are bug-farms.